# Geopandas Spatial Joins - unable to import geopandas.tools

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I currently do my GIS work in Python using a combination of Pandas and ArcPy. I recently heard of Geopandas and am interested in learning to use this as an alternative to ArcPy for basic geoprocessing operations (spatial joining points to polygons, intersecting polygons, etc).

I've installed Geopandas and its dependencies (gdal, shapely, fiona, and pyproj).

I found a Geopandas tutorial on spatial joins (http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/geopandas/geopandas/blob/master/examples/spatial_joins.ipynb), which I've been trying to follow under "Spatial Joins between two GeoDataFrames".

The first 4 lines import the necessary modules:

```
import os 
from shapely.geometry import Point
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame, read_file
from geopandas.tools import overlay
```

3 of these lines run successfully, but the 4th does not. I receive the following import error: "ImportError: No module named tools"

Any suggestions as to what is going wrong? Could it be an error with the installation of the dependencies?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What version of geopandas are you using? (see output of `geopandas.__version__`)

Comment: @joris it's version 0.1.1. I used the Windows installation instructions found on the following blog - http://geoffboeing.com/2014/09/using-geopandas-windows/ (install the dependencies and then pip install geopandas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geopandas 0.1.0 which is the latest documented release of geopandas was released [on 13 Jul 2014](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/releases) does not contain the tools package [according to github](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/tree/master/geopandas/tools)

You should probably install the latest version of geopandas or pull the repo from github and build it yourself.

Comment: Thanks @firelynx. I installed from github and now can access the tools package.